# How to stop customer account creation using Observer or Plugin in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have use this method for stop creation customer account. but it's not work.

> app -> code -> Vendor -> Module -> Observer -> Customer ->
> CheckUserCreateObserver.php

```
$url = $this->_urlManager->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);

$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();

$this->setRefererUrl($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Via Plugin:

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;

class DisableRegistration
{

    public function afterIsAllowed(Registration $subject, $result)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```